# Pandas merging dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several dataframes that I want to merge, but the problems is that the don't have the same columns and that I want to merge only specific rows. I will show an example so it will be easier:

**MAIN_DF** that I want all to be merge to it:

```
key    A    B    C
0001   1    0    0
0002   1    1    1
0003   0    0    1
```

**DF_1**:

```
key    A    B    C   D
0001   1    0    0   1
0003   0    0    1   0
0004   1    1    1   1
```

**DF_2**:

```
key    C    D    E   F
0004   1    1    0   1
0005   0    0    1   0
0006   1    1    1   1
```

So I want to merge it all to **MAIN_DF**, so MAIN_DF would be:

```
key    A    B    C    D    E   F
0001   1    0    0    1    0   0
0002   1    1    1    0    0   0
0003   0    0    1    0    0   0
0004   0    0    0    1    0   1
0005   0    0    0    0    1   0
0006   0    0    0    1    1   1
```

look that the columns were updated and new rows were added.

is it possible to do it with pandas without doing long and slow loops and if statements?

thank you

Comment: Is row with `0004` correct in output?

Comment: Your bottom left 3 corner cell should read [[1,1,1], [0,0,0], [0,0,1]] from top to bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
MAIN_DF = MAIN_DF.set_index('key')
DF_1 = DF_1.set_index('key')
DF_2 = DF_2.set_index('key')

df = MAIN_DF.combine_first(DF_1).combine_first(DF_2).fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()
print (df)
    key  A  B  C  D  E  F
0  0001  1  0  0  1  0  0
1  0002  1  1  1  0  0  0
2  0003  0  0  1  0  0  0
3  0004  1  1  1  1  0  1
4  0005  0  0  0  0  1  0
5  0006  0  0  1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way to do it with `groupby`.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0, 0],
                    [1, 1, 1],
                    [0, 0, 1]],    columns=['a', 'b', 'c'],      index=[1, 2, 3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0, 0, 1],
                    [0, 0, 1, 0],
                    [1, 1, 1, 1]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], index=[1, 3, 4])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 0, 1],
                    [0, 0, 1, 0],
                    [1, 1, 1, 1]], columns=['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], index=[4, 5, 6])

# combine the first and second df
df4 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
grouped = df4.groupby(level=0)
df5 = grouped.first()

# combine (first and second combined), with the third
df6 = pd.concat([df5, df3])
grouped = df6.groupby(level=0)
df7 = grouped.first()

# fill na values with 0
df7.fillna('0', inplace=True)

print(df)

    a   b   c   d   e   f
1   1   0   0   1   0   0
2   1   1   1   0   0   0
3   0   0   1   0   0   0
4   1   1   1   1   0   1
5   0   0   0   0   1   0
6   0   0   1   1   1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate horizontally as much dataframes you want with concat :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1, verify_integrity=True)
```

The "verify_integrity" argument checks for duplicates.

Go here to know more about [merge, join and concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Comment: yes but please take a notice that I don't want duplicate rows